# Are there any online sites that can translate an escape sequence?

Tags: translation, unicode-escapes

I'm messing with a new project, one that uses the `strace` program on Linux. I ran this command:  `strace -e'read,write' -o /tmp/myprogram.log top` just to get a gist of what `strace` outputs, and I have no clue what half of the output means.

Here's an example of one of these sequences: `\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\220%\0\0004\0\0\0`.

Obviously, this isn't entirely human-readable and I'm kinda curious what exactly it's saying. Especially if I have a bunch of these, translating them by hand is far too time consuming.

Thus, my question. Does anyone know of an online site or utility that allows you to input an escape sequence and have it spit back the formatted string?

Comment: you can simply press [F12] here, click console, and then paste in a quoted version: "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\220%\0\0004\0\0\0"

Comment: Are you sure? When I press F12 it brings up the Firefox page inspector...

Comment: firefox has a console in there somewhere. i get firebug, but i forgot not everyone has that. you can go to http://danml.com/sandbox/ and paste the quoted phrase in the IN box, then click RUN to do about the same thing...